# ansible - run playbooks in parallel

Tags: ansible

I have one ansible playbook which is called from the Jenkins after a nightly build. As you can see each line contains different product component is installed.
Is there a way to run them in parallel? So all playbooks files to server1 will run in serial but playbooks for server1 and server2, should run in parallel.

```
- include: "componentA.yml target=server1"
- include: "componentB.yml target=server1"

- include: "componentC.yml target=server2"
- include: "componentD.yml target=server2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your playbook to target all servers at once and use `strategy: free` with dynamically included tasks. Like this:

```
---
- hosts: server*
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    - include: componentA_tasks.yml
      when: inventory_hostname == 'server1'
    - include: componentB_tasks.yml
      when: inventory_hostname == 'server1'
    - include: componentC_tasks.yml
      when: inventory_hostname == 'server2'
    - include: componentD_tasks.yml
      when: inventory_hostname == 'server2'
```

This way server2 will not wait for every task on server1 to complete and will fast-forward to componentC tasks.

Or you can split your Jenkins pipeline into parallel tasks and execute ansible in separate threads for server1 and server2.

Comment: I have a lot of servers and components and dont want to manage it by jenkins. Using strategy: free option, so I will have to run this playbook in loop each time to pass a different server name? There is no other way to manage it within one playbook file, just to group "include" in blocks and run them in parallel?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Playbooks are supposed to be split into plays, each play supposed to complete identical tasks on a group of servers. For example, deploy database servers first, then deploy application servers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
What is the best practice to manage such a situation. We have around 20 components that deployed in different ways. So I have to keep playback.yml for each component. How to manage installation of all of them on around 7 servers that some of them are windows and some are linux? Now, I just hold install_all.yml which contains a list of includes like I posted in the post above.